# Bash script find and copy files with multiple extensions including files with 2 or 3 extensions

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script to find and copy files to another extension,

```
find . -name '*.so' -name '*.lib' -exec cp{} $destination \
```

The above script will just copy all the .so files to the `$destination`and ignores *.lib. Moreover I have more files in the directory with 2 or 3 extensions, like 
`test.so.55 , test1.so.bkk` ,  etc.

How can I adjust my above code so that it can copy all the `'*.so'` , `'*.lib'` and `'*.so.*'`  files to the `$destination`. 
Furthermore, I have tried using,

```
Try1:

find . -name '*.so' -name '*.lib' -name '*.so.*' -exec cp{} $destination \
```

and Even

```
Try2

find . -name '*.so' -exec cp{} $destination \
find . -name '*.so.*' -exec cp{} $destination \
find . -name '*.lib' -exec cp{} $destination \
```

But the above code will copy just the *.so in the Try 1 and `*.so and *.lib` files in the and doesnot copy `*.so.*` i.e `*.so.55 , *.so.bkk` in the Try 2.

I have thousands of files, How can I adjust my code so that It will copy all
the `*.so , *.lib and *.so.*` to the destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR` clause in your pattern matching:

```
find . \( -name '*.so' -o -name '*.lib' -o -name '*.so.*' \) -exec cp{} $destination \;
```